# GPO-Restrict Internet Access

Tags: windows

I would like to restrict internet access for domain users for the company that I'm working for.

I'm used at doing that with Internet Explorer using Group Policy, but am unable to do so because my server does not have available to me the **Windows Component** node with the relevant policies to configure the lockdown:

[image: server admin template]

How can I restrict internet access via Internet Explorer on client PCs using Group Policy?

Comment: GPO isn't really a good method of preventing users from accessing the internet with any browser. And what exactly do you mean by "restrict?"  Do you mean you just want to block certain websites? Or prevent the user from accessing the internet at all?  I'd use some sort of proxy instead of trying to control this behavior on the workstations.

Answer (score 0):

I have two levels of internet restriction, both use the host firewall and block outbound connections by default. At the top level I only allow connections to non-routable IP space (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16) effectively blocking all internet access. At the next level, I also allow connections to my organizations IP space which I got from the network team; this allows internet access to only IPs managed by my org. Both of these sets of rules are in separate GPOs and applied to security groups containing the target computers. I also had to create a scheduled task that disables any other firewall rules that get re-created after Windows Update.